# Codeigniter - Create two or more result objects from single query

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, mysqli

Please look at this code:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM comments c LEFT JOIN users u ON u.user_id = c.user_id");
foreach ($query->result('Comment') as $comment)
{
// $comment holds all data from both tables
}
```

So, what I want is to have two objects `$comment` (only with columns from comments table as object properties) and `$user` for that comment. **Is there any simple way to get that?**

Please note that this is general question and I need all columns from both tables and sometimes columns in one table can have names as columns in other tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution whitch works very fine for me now. Everything what I need is to use PDO.
Here is my code now:

```
$this->db->conn_id->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_FETCH_TABLE_NAMES, 1);
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM comments c LEFT JOIN users u ON u.user_id = c.user_id");
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
    $comment = row2object($row, 'Comment', 'c');
    $comment->user = row2object($row, 'User', 'u');

    $comments[] = $comment;
}
```

And row2object() helper:

```
/**
 * Row to object
 * application/helpers/row2object_helper.php
 *
 * @param array $row
 * @param string $class
 * @param string $from_table alias of table name
 */
function row2object(&$row, $class, $from_table)
{
    $object = new $class;

    foreach($row as $key => $value)
    {
        list($table, $column) = explode(".", $key);

        if($table == $from_table)
        {
            $object->{$column} = $value;
            unset($row[$key]);
        }
        elseif ($table == "" && substr($key, 1, strlen($from_table)) == $from_table)
        {
            $column = substr($key, strlen($from_table) + 2);
            $object->{$column} = $value;
            unset($row[$key]);
        }
    }

    return $object;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside of that foreach you can do something like this:

```
foreach ($query->result('Comment') as $comments)
{
    $comment[$comments->getCommentId()] = $comments->getCommentInfo();
    $user[$comments->getCommentId()] = $comment->getUserInfo();

}
```

And on the Comment Class you should create a method that returns all the user specific data and another method for specific Comment information, you may also clear that information from the current instance as you call the method.

That way, you will get what you wanted in separate variables, as arrays for each comment.

Comment: thx, I can implement something like that, but what if tables users and comments have columns with the same name, for example `email`?

Comment: You should either use an Alias or change the field names to something like, commentEmail and userEmail.

Either way, you will rename the fields in your resulting queries.

An alias is created like this on your query, SELECT comment.email AS commentEmail, user.email AS userEmail,(all the fields you need) FROM (...)

Answer (score 0):

The approach described here is better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10803244/385402 because it involves obtaining related objects with lazy loading (on-demand)