# How can I use business objects to wrap logic in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, business-logic

I have been using Codeigniter for a while, and I would like to have business objects that handle the logic, something like this:

```
$comment = new Comment($this->input->post());
$blog = new Blog();
$current_post = $blog->get_current_post();
$current_post->add_comment($comment);

$data['current_post'] = $current_post;
$this->load->view('post_view',$data);
```

Instead of this approach:

```
$this->load->model('comment_model');
$this->load->model('blog_model');
$this->load->model('post_model');

$comment = $this->comment_model->create_from_array($this->input->post());
$blog = $this->blog_model->get_blog();
$current_post = $this->post_model->get_current_post($blog);
$this->post_model->add_comment($current_post,$comment);

$data['current_post'] = $current_post;
$this->load->view('post_view',$data);
```

Comment: Makes no sense to me. Object-orientation is the wrong paradigm for a server. I can still remember the Java Enterprise Beans horror.

The CI appraoch is in fact that of a Singleton (design pattern) (every load extends the Singleton hierarchy). Which makes more sense. Still weird, but workable weird. A good metaphore for an server is a electronic circuit, with the transformation logic (circuit-board) hardwired and the request (input) being transformed to the response (output).

Aside from that :) your question is vague. What kind of answer do you need?

Comment: I found that the closest solution is [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10803244/385402

Comment: @PatrickSavalle it is a real question, about use objects (our own objects) to do some actions, its question have perfectly logic, I stay here with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is changing how codeigniter works, without loading models how will it know where to fetch the data from? If you want to do it the way you suggested you are going to have to extend the Core controller class and make alot of assumptions about your code. For example when you make a new instance Comment() it should load a model, and an argument passed to it should access a certain method in that model.

You will simply be making a nice wrapper for the functionality that exists already, which is fine, but in the end you code may look nicer but it will still work the same.