# codeigniter, result() vs. result_array()

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use both `result()` and `result_array()`.

Usually i like to get my result as array thats why i use result_array() mostly..

But i want to know which is the better approach that i should follow,
Which one of them is more efficient to use in regards to performance?

Here is the Example i am talking about in codeigniter queries

```
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result_array();
```

or is this should be the better approach??

```
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result();
```

also right now i am using result_array in my generic model.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Result has an optional `$type` parameter which decides what type of result is returned. By default (`$type = "object"`), it returns an object (`result_object()`). It can be set to `"array"`, then it will return an array of result, that being equivalent of caling `result_array()`. The third version accepts a custom class to use as a result object.

The code from CodeIgniter:

```
/**
* Query result. Acts as a wrapper function for the following functions.
*
* @param string $type 'object', 'array' or a custom class name
* @return array
*/
public function result($type = 'object')
{
    if ($type === 'array')
    {
        return $this->result_array();
    }
    elseif ($type === 'object')
    {
        return $this->result_object();
    }
    else
    {
        return $this->custom_result_object($type);
    }
}
```

Arrays are technically faster, but they are not objects. It depends where do you want to use the result. Most of the time, arrays are sufficient.

Answer (score 7):

for the sake of reference:

```
// $query->result_object() === $query->result()
// returns:
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [col_A] => val_1A , [col_B] => val_1B , ... ) 
        [0] => stdClass Object ( [col_A] => val_2A , [col_B] => val_2B , ... ) 
        ...  
      ) 

// $query->result_array() !== $query->result()
// returns:
Array ( [0] => Array ( [col_A] => val_1A , [col_B] => val_1B , ... ) 
        [1] => Array ( [col_A] => val_2A , [col_B] => val_2B , ... )
        ... 
      )
```

[codeigniter docs for result(), and result_array()](http://localhost/shannonburnett.net/website/v02/user_guide/database/results.html?highlight=row_array#id1)

Answer (score 4):

`result_array()` is faster,
`result()` is easier

Answer (score 3):

result() returns Object type data.
.
.
.
result_array() returns Associative Array type data.

Answer (score 1):

Returning pure array is slightly faster than returning an array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

`result()` is recursive in that it returns an std class object where as `result_array()` just returns a pure array, so `result_array()` would be choice regarding performance.  There is very little difference in speed though.

Answer (score 0):

`result_array()` returns Associative Array type data. Returning pure array is slightly faster than returning an array of objects. `result()` is recursive in that it returns an std class object where as `result_array()` just returns a pure array, so `result_array()` would be choice regarding performance.

Answer (score -1):

in my experince the problem using `result()` and `result_array()` in my `JSON` if using `result()` there no problem its works but if using `result_array()` i got error `"Trying to get property of non-object"` so im not search into deep the problem so i just using `result()` if using `JSON` and using `result_array()` if not using `JSON`