# CodeIgniter: Function call result_array() gives error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm getting this error for like a hour, what's this error on codeigniter

Here is my model:

i described property for fields too

```
class news_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();  
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function get_news($id = false)
    {
        if ($id === false) {
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT tbl_news.id,
                                            tbl_news.fa_name,
                                            tbl_news.en_name,
                                            tbl_news.fa_shrt_name,
                                            tbl_news.en_shrt_name,
                                            tbl_news.fa_text,
                                            tbl_news.en_text,
                                            tbl_news.image,
                                            tbl_news.grp_id,
                                            tbl_news_grp.fa_name FROM tbl_news JOIN tbl_news_grp ON tbl_news_grp.id = tbl_news.id ");

            return $query->result_array();
        }

        $query = $this->db->get_where('tbl_news',array('id' => $id));
        return $query->result_array();
    }
}
```

I get this error :

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function result_array() on a non-object in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\ipkoroosh\application\models\news_model.php on line 19
```

Comment: could you please give a bit more of code, looks like there is some issue with object making and useage

Comment: @Arihant what about now?

Comment: Did you loaded the database in constructor ???   $this->load->database();

Comment: you can see it that i did ;)

Comment: These fields are not selected with their related table names fa_shrt_name, en_shrt_name, fa_text, en_text, grp_id, image. They may be ambigous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How your where condition work you have no query above this and both condition will not run at a time so need to use else and refine query according you

```
public function get_news($id = false)
    {
        if ($id === false) {
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT tblnews.*,tblnewsgrp.* FROM tbl_news tblnews JOIN tbl_news_grp tblnewsgrp ON tblnewsgrp.id = tblnews.id");

            return $query->result_array();
        }
        else {
           $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_news WHERE id = '$id'");
            return $query->result_array();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Result has an optional $type parameter which decides what type of result is returned. By default ($type = "object"), it returns an object (result_object()). It can be set to "array", then it will return an array of result, that being equivalent of caling result_array(). The third version accepts a custom class to use as a result object.

```
/**
* Query result. Acts as a wrapper function for the following functions.
*
* @param string $type 'object', 'array' or a custom class name
* @return array
*/
public function result($type = 'object')
{
if ($type === 'array')
{
    return $this->result_array();
}
elseif ($type === 'object')
{
    return $this->result_object();
}
else
{
    return $this->custom_result_object($type);
}
}
```

Reference: [Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16506789/codeigniter-result-vs-result-array)

Answer (score 0):

Check your query properly i think it is not giving result so this error is there.

Check it with this.
$query->result();

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
return $query->get()->result_array();
```

instead

```
return $query->result_array();
```

Comment: i used $this->db->query() so i don't think that's gonna work 
here's the result by the way : Call to a member function get() on a non-object

Answer (score 0):

Try to print your SQL query by using $this->db->last_query(); and run the query on mysql console. There may be errors in SQL query.

Please check