# PHP variable not recognized in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

In my javascript I am trying to pass a php variable through the html name tag. The html is appended to my selected options.

```
$("#a"+$selected.val()).append('<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $event_id; ?>" value="'+$selected.text()+'">');
```

Here is the entire js function to see what is going on http://laravel.io/bin/Edz25

Now, I know for a fact and have tested in my view that $event_id is returning an array by doing the following in my controller and also echoing the variable in the view.

```
print_r($event_id);
die();
```

Controller:

```
$data['event_id'] = $this->model_location->get_event_id();
```

Model:

```
public function get_event_id()
{

    $this->db->select('id');
    $query = $this->db->get('table_eventcards');

    return $query->result_array();


}
```

Now I am not sure why the variable in my javascript is not outputting anything.

Here is the output when I inspect the element.

```
<li data-value="28" id="a28">Event title<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $event_id; ?>" value="Event title"></li>
```

If this helps this is my console log http://postimg.org/image/owtz3v8h7/

I really need to get this solved and appreciate all help.

Comment: "$ is not defined". Do you load jQuery BEFORE you run your script?

Comment: Are you sure that that page is being processed by PHP?

Comment: @lesssugar The script is in a carabiner loaded at the footer of every page which loads the jquery sources. If all my other jquery is working I do not see this as an issue that would effect the php variable.

Comment: *"I know for a fact that `$event_id` is returning an array"*, and how do you expect to use an array as a name ?

Comment: You are using a separated JS file or <script> tags for javascript?

Comment: @PatrickQ Not following you. Are you saying is the javascript locations.js being processed by PHP where the js function is.

Comment: @adeneo It needs to have the id of the event related to user returned in the name so that it could be grabbed and stored in the db later.

Comment: .js files do not go through the PHP interpreter (unless you have some crazy custom setup to specify that they do). So any PHP code that you have inside a .js file will not be treated as PHP.

Comment: @PatrickQ Then how in the world do I pass an array of ids to the name tag. Passing it through the form_dropdown in the parameter does not work.

Comment: With data attributes or a script tag

Comment: @adeneo can you be more specific. The data attributes passed in parameter does not work to pass to each selected option. What do you mean with script tag?

Comment: http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Comment: I am passing data-value already but do not understand how to pass in the name what I need.

Comment: To be completely honest, it seems like you need more help than fits within the scope of this question. You should try some basic jQuery, HTML5, and CodeIgniter (it looks like you're using CodeIgniter, right?) tutorials.

Comment: @Patrick Q Not sure why my question was down voted. I asked a legitimate question and showed what I tried.

Comment: And you're addressing that to me ... why?

Comment: @PatrickQ No not to you specifically, just wanted someone to re-correct the down vote since I have a valid question.

Answer (score 1):

The .js files included in the HTML are not parsed by PHP, for do this you can use < script> tags and write this variables, example:

First, write your variable in the php file:

mypage.php

```
 <script>
     var MY_VAR = "<?php echo $myVar; ?>";
 <script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="my_script.js"></script>
```

And then you can use this variable on your js file:

my_script.js

```
$("#a"+$selected.val()).append('<input type="hidden" name="' + MY_VAR + '" value="'+$selected.text()+'">');
```

A tested example:

```
<?php
     $myVar = 1;
 ?>

 <script>
     var MY_VAR = "<?php echo $myVar; ?>";
     alert(MY_VAR);
 </script>
```

The alert output will be "1"

Comment: I added the script tag on the php page. Then added the js variable in my .js page. It still give the same output treating the php variable as a string.

Comment: The js variable set to php variable in view is passing to .js file. However, strangely the alert is not working on the same view.

Answer (score 0):

[CodeIgniter's `result_array()` will return a multidimensional array.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16506789/2943403)

Your ActiveRecord query doesn't appear to include any filtration (no WHERE clause), so there is the possibility that several rows will be returned.

Even if there is only one row in the table, the result set will be like:

```
array (
    array(
        'id' => 1
    )
)
```

Ergo, `$data['event_id']` (in the contoller) AND `$event_id` (in the view) will contain the above data structure.

Some advice on variable naming... if a variable contains more than one of something (aka isIterable), then use a plural variable name so that you aren't confusing future developers of your script (the next developer might actually be you).

Adding to the confusion, you seem to be trying to assign the hidden input's name as an array -- I really don't understand the intent here.

If you want a specific `id`, you need to pull it from the array.  If you want to iterate the array of `id`s, then you will need to adjust your js process.

Either way, to pass the data from server-side (php) to client-side (javascript), you will have stable success in the long term, if you use `json_encode()` (avoiding quoting and quote escaping issues).

```
<script>
let event_id = <?php echo json_encode($event_id); ?>;
</script>
```

Then makes sure that the external script that will use `event_id` is loaded AFTER the view renders the above javascript declaration.