# Can't pass data from model to view

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello i'm having problem on passing some data from my Model to my View, with this following code:

Controller:

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {


    function __construct()
     {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('url');

     }
    public function testing(){

      $query = $this->Model->getEmployees();
      if(isset($query)){
       $data['fds'] =  $query;
      }

      $this->load->view('UserPage', $data);
     }
}
```

Model:

```
class Model extends CI_Model{

 function __construct()
     {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->library('session');
     }

 public function getEmployees(){
        $this->db->select('*');
         $this->db->where("idcliente='".$_SESSION['userid']."'");
         $query=$this->db->get('marcacao');
        return $query->num_rows() > 0 ? $query->result() : NULL;
 }
}
```

View:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
     <tr> 
      <td><strong>Employee Id</strong></td>
      <td><strong>First Name</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Last Name</strong></td>
    </tr> 
     <?php foreach($fds as $employee){?>
     <tr>
      <td><? =$employee->data;?></td>
      <td><? =$employee->hora;?></td>
      <td><? =$employee->tipo;?></td>
     </tr>     
        <?php }?>  
    </table>
```

I've tried several things that I've seen here but none works... Hope you can help me.

Comment: *"I've tried several things..."* ~ what several things?  Be specific.  What kind of troubleshooting have you done?  Are you sure that your `$query` variable contains something and it's in the format you expect?

Comment: It contains something yes and what do you mean, the format I expect? @Sparky

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/16506789/594235

Comment: Alright, I changed $query->result() : NULL; to $query->result_arry() : NULL;
Still doesn't work, keeps telling me "Undefined variable: fds"

Comment: I did not suggest that you change it... I simply asked if you knew what it was and what you expect it to be.   Otherwise:   What several things have you tried? Be specific. What kinds of troubleshooting have you done?  You should have included any error messages in your OP.  Use the "edit" link above.

Comment: It doesn't let me edit it, i don't know why... I try to write but it auto deletes everything I write.

Answer (score 0):

first things change this :

```
  $query = $this->Model->getEmployees();
  if(isset($query)){
   $data['fds'] =  $query;
  }
```

become  :

```
$id = $_SESSION['userid'];
$data["fds"] = $this->Model->getEmployees($id);
```

now on your model :

```
public function getEmployees($id){
     $this->db->select('*');
     $this->db->where("idcliente=",$id);
     $query=$this->db->get('marcacao');
     return $query->result_array();
```

now in your view()

```
<?php
 if($fds != NULL){
 foreach($fds as $employee){?>
   <tr>
     <td><?=$employee["data"];?></td>
     <td><?=$employee["hora"];?></td>
     <td><?=$employee["tipo"];?></td>
   </tr>     
 <?php 
 }
  }?>
```

Comment: Did all that, keeps giving me the "Undefined variable: fds" error :(

Comment: dont forget to add `$data` when you load your view in controller, and that in your parent construct controller  dont forget to add `$this->load->model("your_model")`

Answer (score 0):

First of all as i can see in your code the variable `$data` is initialized inside the if block so its scope will remain within that if block only. Also before calling a model you are suppose to load the model.

```
public function testing(){
      $data = array();
      $this->load->model("Model");
      $query = $this->Model->getEmployees();
      if(isset($query)){
       $data['fds'] =  $query;
      }
      $this->load->view('UserPage', $data);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Doing This ....

For Controller :

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {


function __construct()
 {
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->model('Model'); 

 }
public function testing(){

  $query = $this->Model->getEmployees(); // replace "Model_name" with the name of your model

  $data = array();
  if(isset($query)){
   $data['fds'] =  $query;
  }

  $this->load->view('UserPage', $data);
 } }
```

For Model :

```
 class Model extends CI_Model{

 function __construct()
     {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->database();
     }

 public function getEmployees(){
        $this->db->select('*');
         $this->db->where("idcliente='".$_SESSION['userid']."'");
         $query=$this->db->get('marcacao');
         if($query->num_rows() > 0) 
             { return $query->result(); } 
               else{ return NULL; }
 }
}
```

Now for the view named UserPage.php

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
 <tr> 
  <td><strong>Employee Id</strong></td>
  <td><strong>First Name</strong></td>
  <td><strong>Last Name</strong></td>
</tr> 
 <?php foreach($fds as $employee){?>
 <tr>
  <td><? =$employee->data;?></td>
  <td><? =$employee->hora;?></td>
  <td><? =$employee->tipo;?></td>
 </tr>     
    <?php }?>  
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out... Had to put this in the model function:

```
$this->load->database();
```