# getting an undefined index return date in codeigniter 3 even after getting values from database?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I am fetching values from database and the values are successfully shown when i use print_r but i get an error when i try to echo the values out it gives me an error of Message:

> Undefined index: return_date

my code for controller is as follows

```
public function latebooks(){
    $now = date('m/d/Y');
    $this->load->model('Time');
    $id=$this->session->userdata('userid');
    $this->load->model('Department');
    $table=$this->Department->selecttable($id);
    foreach($table as $q){}
    $table = $q->department_name;
    $table = strtolower($table);
    $run=$this->Time->timecalculations($table);
    print_r($run);
    $this->load->view('Books/datetime',['query'=>$run]);
}
```

and my code for my model is as follows:

```
public function timecalculations($table){
    $query= $this->db->get_where('issue_books',array('department_id'=>$table));
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

and the code in the view is as follows

```
    <?php

/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: workspace
 * Date: 05-10-2016
 * Time: 13:46
 */
include 'header.php';
?>
<br /><br />
<?php
echo $query['return_date'];
?>
<?php
include 'footer.php';
?>
```

please forgive as i am novice here!Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the result of `print_r($run);`? in controller? `$query->result()` this will return the object not an array

Comment: @devpro it is returning me the output clearly shows it like a array

Comment: you made a mistake here, `foreach($table as $q){}
    $table = $q->department_name;
    $table = strtolower($table);` It should be inside the foreach loop or 
use `$table = $table[0]->department_name`

Comment: please show the array here

Comment: show the result of this array `print_r($run);` in contrller or `print_r($query)` in your view file, show me any one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `result()` function in your MODEL for getting records, this will return data into object form not in array.

This:

```
echo $query['return_date'];
```

Should be:

```
echo $query->return_date;
```

---

After your modification in your question, you must need to check what are you getting in `print_r($run)`.

*If you have data in multi-dimensional array than you can use loop here, this will print all data either having one record or multiple.*

```
<?php
foreach ($query as $key => $value) {
    echo $value->return_date;
}
?>
```

*If you want to use `result_array()` function than you can use like:*

```
<?php
foreach ($query as $key => $value) {
    echo $value['return_date'];
}
?>
```

*This post will help you to understand both functions: [codeigniter, result() vs. result_array()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16506789/codeigniter-result-vs-result-array)*

Answer (score 1):

Change this `return $query->result();` in your model as follows

```
return $query->result_array();
```

** `return $query->result();` this returns as object. If want to use this then access data like `echo $query->return_date;`

Answer (score 1):

`$query->result()` returns an array of objects, because it doesn't know whether there's supposed to be 1 result or 100,000 results. To just fetch a single result, you'd use `$query->row()` instead.

But that would still give you the result as an object instead of an array, so if you want to use `$query['return_date']` in your view, you'd use `$query->row_array()` to get the row as an array.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller make these following changes.

```
$run['data']=$this->Time->timecalculations($table);
$this->load->view('Books/datetime',$run);
```

In your view page

```
echo $data[0]['return_date'];
```