# Codeigniter - controller can't send data to view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I got an error like this :

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: tasks

**controller**

```
 public function show() {
    $data['tasks'] = array();
    $data['tasks'] = $this->Tasks_model->show_task()->result();
    $this->load->view('pages/all', $data);
 }
```

**view**

```
<?php 
  if( isset($tasks) && ( is_array($tasks) && count($tasks)>0 ) ) {
    //echo"<pre>"; print_r($tasks); die();
    for($i=0;$i<count($tasks);$i++)
    { ?>
    <span><?php echo $task[0]['job']; ?></span><br />
   <?php } ?>
<?php } 
else { ?>
<span>No tasks records found.</span>
<?php } ?>
```

**Model**

```
public function show_task() {
    return $this->db->get('task');
}
```

what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Please update question and put your full updated View code.

Comment: please read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16506789/codeigniter-result-vs-result-array

Answer (score 0):

**Controller**

```
public function show() {
    $this->$data['tasks'] = array();
    $this->$data['tasks'] = $this->Tasks_model->show_task();
    $this->load->view('pages/all', $data);
}
```

**View**

//Here, you can also use `for` loop to display data.

```
<?php 
if( isset($tasks) && ( is_array($tasks) && count($tasks)>0 ) )
{
    //echo"<pre>"; print_r($tasks); die();
    for($i=0;$i<count($tasks);$i++)
    { ?>
    <span><?php echo $task[0]['job']; ?></span><br />
   <?php } ?>
<?php } 
else { ?>
<span>No tasks records found.</span>
<?php } ?>
```

**EDIT =>**

**Model**

```
public function show_task() {
    $query = $this->db->get('task');
    if( $query->num_rows() > 0 ) //Always check you are getting result or not.
    {
        return $query->result_array(); //result_array() returns the query result as a pure array
    }
    else
    {
        return array();
    }
}
```

Here you are returning `return $this->db->get('task');` directly. So you are not getting anythingin View.
First you have to assign `$this->db->get('task')` to variable e.g. `$query` and pass result array to controller `return $query->result_array();`.

Reference => https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html#result-arrays

Comment: the output is no task records found. it means that, i still can't get the data. here if you want to see the full code: https://pastebin.com/YKjbgCr2

Comment: Yes. you are not getting data from Model.

Comment: @BeingShame I have updated my answer. Please refer it.

Comment: the result is still "No tasks records found.". I'm starting to think that the problem lies elsewhere. If i don't use those condition in view, the error will be "undefined variable: tasks".

Comment: @BeingShame I have made changes to Controller. `$this->$data['tasks'] = $this->Tasks_model->show_task();` Here previously `$this->` was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

```
 public function show() {
    $data['tasks'] = array();
    $data['tasks'] = $this->Tasks_model->show_task();
    $this->load->view('pages/all', $data);
 }
```

Model:

```
public function show_task() {
    return $this->db->get('task')->result();
}
```

View Page:

```
<?php 
if( isset($tasks) && ( is_array($tasks) && count($tasks)>0 ) )
{
    //echo"<pre>"; print_r($tasks); die();
    for($i=0;$i<count($tasks);$i++)
    { ?>
    <span><?php echo $task[0]['job']; ?></span><br />
   <?php } ?>
<?php } 
else { ?>
<span>No tasks records found.</span>
<?php } ?>
```